# How can I plot this 'integral' code in R?

Tags: r, plot, integral

```
f1 <- function(x){integrate(f = function(t){
  sqrt(t^3-1)
}, lower = 1, upper = x)}
```

The domain of `x` is `1` to `4`. `f1` always emit value characterized 'integrate'. I don't know how to plot this integral function in R.
Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to compute the values of your function f1 and then use an apply function as follows:

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  integrate( function(t) sqrt(t^3-1), lower = 1, upper = x)
}
u <- seq(1, 4, by = 0.1) # Defining a vector of values from 1 to 4 in steps of .1
f1u <- sapply(u, function(x) f1(x)$value) #computing the values of f1 over u
plot(u,f1u, type = "l", xlab = "x", ylab = "f1(x)") # your plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul! You gave me a help a lot.

Comment: Glad to help, please, consider upvoting and accepting the answer.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize the `upper` argument to `integrate` like so:

```
vintegrate <- Vectorize(integrate, "upper")

f1 <- function(x) {
  unlist(vintegrate(function(t) sqrt(t^3-1), lower = 1, upper = x)[1,])
}
```

Then you can plot using the `curve` function in base `R`:

```
curve(f1(x), from = 1, to = 4)
```

[image]

Or using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x  = 0)) + 
  geom_function(fun = f1) +
  xlim(1, 4)
```

[image]

---

Without vectorizing, the `upper` argument expects an vector of length 1 or else it will error:

```
integrate(function(t) sqrt(t^3-1), lower = 1, upper = 1:4)
Error in integrate(function(t) sqrt(t^3 - 1), lower = 1, upper = 1:4) : 
  length(upper) == 1 is not TRUE
```

After vectorizing:

```
vintegrate(function(t) sqrt(t^3-1), lower = 1, upper = 1:4)
             [,1]       [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        
value        0          1.515927     5.356315     11.84309    
abs.error    0          0.0001312847 0.0003641383 0.0006563824
subdivisions 1          5            5            5           
message      "OK"       "OK"         "OK"         "OK"        
call         Expression Expression   Expression   Expression
```

And we use `unlist` and `[1,]` to get the `value`.